# test class passesdwith 50 % code coverage but excute method variables not covering

Tags: unit-test

batch class

```
public  class AUditingBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{
public Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
//string query = 'Select Action__c,Display__c,Section__c, CreatedBy__c.name, CreatedDate__c, DelegateUser__c From AUditTrial__c LIMIT 5'; 
string query1='SELECT Id,Action,DelegateUser,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,Display,Section FROM SetupAuditTrail';
    //QUERY ON API


    return Database.getQueryLocator(query1);
    }
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SetupAuditTrail> scope )
    {
  List<AUditTrial__c> auditList= new List<AUditTrial__c>();//INTIALZE CUSTOM OBJECT
        for(SetupAuditTrail t : scope){ 
        AUditTrial__c AU= new AUditTrial__c(
                   Action__c = t.Action,
                   Name= t.CreatedBy.Name,
                   CreatedBy__c= t.CreatedBy.Name,
                   CreatedDate__c = t.CreatedDate,
                   DelegateUser__c= t.DelegateUser,
                   Display__c= t.Display,
                   Section__c= t.Section);
               auditList.add(AU);
        }
    insert auditList;
    }
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    system.debug('capture the setup audit trial Data finished');
  }
}
```

Test Class

@isTest
public class TestAudingbatch {

```
static Testmethod void  testAU(){ 
    string query = 'Select Action__c,Display__c,Section__c, CreatedBy__c, CreatedDate__c, DelegateUser__c From AUditTrial__c';
 AUditTrial__c[] m1=new List<AUditTrial__c>();

for (integer i=0; i<10;i++)
{
AUditTrial__c a1=new AUditTrial__c(
Action__c ='apexclass',
Display__c='modified',
Section__c='pagelayout');
 m1.add(a1);
}
insert m1;
    Database.QueryLocator QL;
    Database.BatchableContext BC;
    List <SetupAuditTrail> setup=new List<SetupAuditTrail>();
    List<AUditTrial__c> Auditt = new List<AUditTrial__c>();
    test.startTest();
    AUditingBatch AU = new AUditingBatch();
    QL = AU.start(bc);
    AU.finish(BC);
   AU.execute(BC,setup);


    test.stopTest();
}
```

}

Comment: don't forget to do asserts to verify that the code does what you expect; code coverage by itself is not best practice

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing correct Test class for Batch. What you need to do is here a code sample for you.

```
@isTest
private class TestCleanUpBatchClass {

    static testmethod void test() {
        // The query used by the batch job.
        String query = 'SELECT Id,CreatedDate FROM Merchandise__c ' + 
                   'WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Merchandise__c FROM Line_Item__c)';

       // Create some test merchandise items to be deleted
       //   by the batch job.
       Merchandise__c[] ml = new List<Merchandise__c>();
       for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) {
           Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c(
               Name='Merchandise ' + i,
               Description__c='Some description',
               Price__c=2,
               Total_Inventory__c=100);
           ml.add(m);
       }
       insert ml;

       Test.startTest();
       CleanUpRecords c = new CleanUpRecords(query);
       Database.executeBatch(c);
       Test.stopTest();

       Integer i = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Merchandise__c];
       System.assertEquals(i, 0);
    }
}
```

Your modified Test class

```
@isTest
public class TestAudingbatch {


    static Testmethod void  testAU(){ 
       List <SetupAuditTrail> setup=new List<SetupAuditTrail>();
    for(integer i = 0; i<200; i++){
    SetupAuditTrail a1=new SetupAuditTrail(
    a1.Action ='apexclass',
    a1.Display='modified',
    a1.Section='pagelayout');
     setup.add(a1);
    }
    insert add;
   Test.startTest();
        AUditingBatch AU = new AUditingBatch();
       Database.executebatch(au);
   Test.stopTest();

   //asserts here

    }

}
```

Comment: don't forget - Wrap `Database.executeBatch()` in `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` then do asserts

Comment: System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.